# How to deal subject with literal in jena?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have two formats of rdf. Using my developed code deal only one type of RDF. In one rdf i have only class and in another rdf i have class with literal. If i change my code i got following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.LiteralRequiredException: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing

For better under standing i provide two rdf format and my code

One rdf format is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ontology="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/ontology/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Tunedmassdamper">
    <ontology:desciption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">A damper mounted in structures to reduce the amplitude of mechanical vibrations</ontology:desciption>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Localco-investigator">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Projectperson"/>
    <ontology:desciption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">A person who collaborate and communictaion with principal investigator  on study proposal, design and implementation.</ontology:desciption>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://earthquake.linkeddata.it/resource/Pressuresensor">
    <ontology:desciption rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">A sensor which measures pressures, typically gasses or liquids.</ontology:desciption>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And onther rdf format is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:georesource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:geontology="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/ontology/"
    xmlns:dcmibox="http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-box/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali/6226">
    <geontology:length rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">23.0947403412</geontology:length>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">I cunet. dx del i ramo dx</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">6226</rdfs:label>
    <geo:geometry rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali_6226"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali/1650">
    <geontology:length rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">167.800339122</geontology:length>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Rio fontane nere</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">1650</rdfs:label>
    <geo:geometry rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali_1650"/>
  </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

My developed code given bellow:

```java
for (StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(null, RDFS.label,
                (RDFNode) null); iter.hasNext();) {
            Statement stmt = (Statement) iter.next();
            Resource subject = stmt.getSubject();
            String label = stmt.getLiteral().getString();

}
```

if i change my code like bellow

```
for (StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Statement stmt = (Statement) iter.next();
            Resource subject = stmt.getSubject();
            String label = stmt.getLiteral().getString();
}
```

program is terminated for the 1st part of rdf and 2nd part of rdf i got above error message.

Could any body help me how to manage two rdf file using same code?

Answer (score 4):

There are some missing details "....owl#Thing" isn't in your data.

`stmt.getLiteral().getString()` gets the *object* of the statement (see javadoc) which may be a literal but it can also be URI as you code is finding out.

Get the object wth `stmt.getObject()` and test what it is with `.isResource()`/`.isURIResource()` or `.isAnon()` or `.isLiteral()`.

Note also you have language tagged literals.

`getLexicalForm` is better than `getString`

Comment: I want to get cunet. dx del i ramo dx and Rio fontane nere. where i have to change the code?